# How can a high voltage flyback transformer burn pieces of paper?

Tags: high-voltage

Why is it possible to burn pieces of paper by holding the output of a high-voltage flyback transformer near them? How is the circuit completed if there's no electrical connection between the paper and the flyback's reference?

I would guess the strong electric field at the output tip creates a [displacement current](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Displacement_current) in the paper, which is a bad conductor and therefore heats until burning up. So there's no closed circuit. Is this right?

I mean, for example, an old color CRT TV, with the output touching a piece of paper **on the table, away from the TV's ground**:

[image: Flyback]

Comment: The high voltage punches through most paper, and the high heat of a plasma arc generally is above the combustion temperature of paper.

Comment: @uglyoldbob But I mean pieces of paper on a table, for example, with no electrical connection to the flyback's reference. I edited my question to clarify that.

Comment: Everything is a conductor at high enough voltages and whether something is "part of a closed circuit" is all relative. A vacuum tube has a  vacuum inside between electrodes. If you stick one in a circuit does it make it an open circuit? What about capacitors where there is separation between the plates? What about a 10 GigaOhm resistor on a PCB where the resistance of the PCB is also 10 GigaOhms?

Comment: @DKNguyen I edited my question again. I believe the situations you describe do not apply to the case of a piece of paper lying on the table, away from the flyback's ground, because the circuit could then only be completed at hundreds of kiloVolts, far above the flyback's operating voltage

Comment: Draw a picture showing parts and distances.

Comment: _"for example, an old CRT TV"_ - color, or b&w?

Comment: @Andyaka I added a picture.

Comment: @BruceAbbott Color

Comment: Was there a smell of ozone?

Comment: @Andyaka Yes indeed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Was there a smell of ozone?

> *@Andyaka Yes indeed*

It's a [corona discharge](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Corona_discharge) - the air becomes ionized around the HV terminal at the plug end of the wire. It will also produce ozone that you can smell. It's not a displacement current, it's real charge carriers floating around the electrode.

I expect that if you turned the lights down you would see a slight purple glow around the terminal in close proximity with the paper.

If it can "do stuff" to air it can probably "do stuff" to paper - I expect that atoms in the paper are also ionized and this will discolour the paper.